# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have run into an HTTP 500 error despite following a tutorial.
Below are the codes for the projects.

HibernateConfig

```
package com.weesheng.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.weesheng.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:config.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.weesheng.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

WebConfig

```
package com.weesheng.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.weesheng" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
 }

 @Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
  InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

  return viewResolver;
 }

}
```

WebInitializer

```
package com.weesheng.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

CouponController

```
package com.weesheng.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.weesheng.model.Coupon;
import com.weesheng.service.CouponService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/coupon")
public class CouponController {

    @Autowired
    CouponService couponService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("coupon/list");
        List<Coupon> list = couponService.listAllCoupons();
        model.addObject("list", list);

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("coupon/form");
        Coupon coupon = couponService.findcouponById(id);
        model.addObject("couponForm", coupon);

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        couponService.deletecoupon(id);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/coupon/list");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView add() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("coupon/form");
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
        model.addObject("couponForm", coupon);

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("couponForm") Coupon coupon) {
        couponService.saveOrUpdate(coupon);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/coupon/list");
    }
}
```

CouponDao

```
package com.weesheng.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.weesheng.model.Coupon;

public interface CouponDao {

     public List<Coupon> listAllcoupons();

     public void saveOrUpdate(Coupon coupon);

     public Coupon findcouponById(int id);

     public void deletecoupon(int id);
}
```

CouponDaoImpl

```
package com.weesheng.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.weesheng.model.Coupon;

@Repository
public class CouponDaoImpl implements CouponDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Coupon> listAllcoupons() {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Coupon.class);
        return (List<Coupon>) criteria.list();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(Coupon coupon) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(coupon);

    }

    public Coupon findcouponById(int id) {
        Coupon coupon = (Coupon) getSession().get(Coupon.class, id);
        return coupon;
    }

    public void deletecoupon(int id) {
        Coupon coupon = (Coupon) getSession().get(Coupon.class, id);
        getSession().delete(coupon);
    }

}
```

Coupon

```
package com.weesheng.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "coupon")
public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "currency")
    private String Currency;

    @Column(name = "times")
    private String times;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return Currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public String getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(String times) {
        this.times = times;
    }
}
```

CouponService

```
package com.weesheng.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.weesheng.model.Coupon;

public interface CouponService {

     public List<Coupon> listAllCoupons();

     public void saveOrUpdate(Coupon coupon);

     public Coupon findcouponById(int id);

     public void deletecoupon(int id);
}
```

CouponServiceImpl

```
package com.weesheng.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.weesheng.dao.CouponDao;
import com.weesheng.model.Coupon;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CouponServiceImpl implements CouponService {

    CouponDao couponDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setCouponDao(CouponDao couponDao) {
        this.couponDao = couponDao;
    }

    public List<Coupon> listAllCoupons() {
        return couponDao.listAllcoupons();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(Coupon coupon) {
        couponDao.saveOrUpdate(coupon);
    }

    public Coupon findcouponById(int id) {
        return couponDao.findcouponById(id);
    }

    public void deletecoupon(int id) {
        couponDao.deletecoupon(id);
    }


}
```

config.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

Error

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.listAllCoupons(Unknown Source)
    com.weesheng.controller.CouponController.list(CouponController.java:26)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.listAllCoupons(Unknown Source)
    com.weesheng.controller.CouponController.list(CouponController.java:26)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.listAllCoupons(Unknown Source)
    com.weesheng.controller.CouponController.list(CouponController.java:26)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2118)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2142)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.listAllCoupons(Unknown Source)
    com.weesheng.controller.CouponController.list(CouponController.java:26)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

[image: Database mysql screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual error is this:

```
The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

As it says, you either need to configure your server with the correct timezone. Or set the  "serverTimezone" property on your JDBC driver URL. Example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the fix I needed

`jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false`